# How can fetch reference table without using repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to fetch Card without using CardRepo like below

```
@Column(name = "account_number")
protected String accountNumber;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_number", referencedColumnName = "account_number", insertable = false, updatable = false)
protected Set<Card> cards;
```

But it doesn't work. I cannot start server.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. I missed to implement Serializable for that entity.

But I don't know why we need implement Serializable for enity.

However it works now.